# Error building node template: file name too long

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I'm trying to build the latest substrate node template (without any modifications so far) and I'm getting the following error:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/adam/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/adam/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-ad88fbc205f4690c/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/adam/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.63.0-nightly (c35035cef 2022-05-30)

...

  error: could not write output to /home/adam/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/node_template_runtime.pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api-437328d54dff4516.pallet_transaction_payment_rpc_runtime_api.abf1d522-cgu.0.rcgu.o.rcgu.o: File name too long

  error: could not compile `node-template-runtime-wasm` due to previous error
```

**Environment:**

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
77580317443b1b66a110d2a547e4c9f8bdca4d73
$ cargo -V
cargo 1.61.0 (a028ae4 2022-04-29)
$ rustc -V
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it was caused by `ecryptfs` file name length limit which is only 143 characters (compared to 255 in most filesystems). I applied a (kinda ugly) workaround described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156392) and mounted a new ext4 filesystem for the `target` directory.

```
$ df -Th
...
/home/adam/.Private ecryptfs  432G   34G  377G   9% /home/adam
/dev/loop18         ext4      9,8G  3,5G  5,8G  38% /home/adam/substrate-node-template/target
```

Comment: other options also could be:  
  a) just moving project dir somewhere out of the `home` dir, or  
  b) set [build.target-dir](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildtarget-dir) to be some path outside your `home` dir